# Tensorflow have different results on GPU and CPU

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
new_global_step = global_step + 1
group_op = tf.group([global_step.assign(new_global_step)])
sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run([group_op, global_step])
```

On GPU, it results [None, 0].
On CPU, it results [None, 1].

Comment: what TF version did you use and how did you print the result? I tested the above code on TF 1.14 and in printed [None, 1] on both GPU and CPU

Comment: @chikara li, It is a bug. Please raise the same in Github at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues. Thanks!